# Mapping an array and adding a comma, but no adding the space after

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to map an array of strings into a comma separated list of buttons.  My code is adding the comma just fine, but is not adding the space after all of the items except the last one, resulting in something like this:

*One,Two,Three,Four* rather rather than *One, Two, Three, Four*

Can someone please clue me into why?

**Here is my map:**

```
   {
     equipArray.map((item, index, array) => {
       return (
         <span key={`${index}`}>
           {(() => {
             if (item.toLowerCase() === 'none') { return 'None'; }
             else
               { return (
                  <> 
                   <button{item}</button>
                   {index !== array.length - 1 ? ', ' : ''}
                  </>
               ); }
           })()}
         </span>
       );
     })
   }
```

Comment: in map, it's not `(item, i, index)` instead, it is `(item, index, array)`

Comment: Just look at [MDN's documentation of `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)...

Comment: please use `(<button>{item}</button>{i !== (index.length - 1) ? ',' + ' ' : ''})` instead of `(<button>{item}{i !== (index.length - 1) ? ',' + ' ' : ''}</button>)`

Comment: I have updated the code with the corrections recommended.  Works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the map callback parameter in confusing names, that's why in the code it makes confusion that will cause typos.

in map, it's not (item, i, index) instead, it is (item, index, array)

```
{
equipArray.map((item, index, array) => {
  return (
    <span key={`${index}`}>
      {(() => {
        if (item.toLowerCase() === "none") return "None"
        else
          return (
            <button>
              {item}
              {index !== array.length - 1 ? "," + " " : ""}
            </button>
          )
      })()}
    </span>
  )
})
```

```js
const equipArray = ['one', 'two', 'three']
const result = equipArray.map((item, index, array) => {
  return `${item}${index !== (array.length - 1) ? ',' + ' ' : ''}`
})
console.log(result)
```

And also it depends on the implementation detail of your code, but I believe that the comma should be after the button element and not inside of it.

So instead of:

```
<button>
  {item}
  {index !== array.length - 1 ? "," + " " : ""}
</button>
```

Just write it afterwards

```
<span>
  <button>{item}</button>
  {index !== array.length - 1 ? "," + " " : ""}
</span>
```

Full code once again:

```
equipArray.map((item, index, array) => {
  return (
    <span key={`${index}`}>
      {(() => {
        if (item.toLowerCase() === "none") return "None"
        else
          return (
            <>
              <button>{item}</button>
              {index !== array.length - 1 ? "," + " " : ""}
            </>
          )
      })()}
    </span>
  )
})
```